# How to check seasonality of quarterly data

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I'm aware of spectral density analysis, but not sure how the frequency would relate to looking for any patterns within the data. Would appreciate any advice on this method or any others.

Another issue is that there are only 39 data points for this time series.